# select query for australian 1 up plan

Tags: sql

can someone give me the select query for australian 1 up plan?

explanation of australian 1 up plan:

say company the company is node "zero"

say "one" is the root affiliate to join a company.(under "zero")
"two" "three" "four" joins under "one"(i,e with referal id of "one")

again in simailar manner 
"five" "six" "seven" joins under "two"
"eight" "nine"  "ten" joins under "three"  and
"eleven" "twelve" "thirteen" joins under "four"

hope the diagram is clear in your mind till now (or plz draw it on a paper)

now the plan is every second member who joins under "one" becomes his downline.(here "three" and "four" are downlines of "one"("two" is not "one's" downline cz "one" is passing "two" for his successor root "zero")

not only "three" and "four" are the downline of "one" but also every first member who joins under "three" or "four" (i,e under downline of "one") are also the downlines of "one"
(i,e "eight and "eleven" are also downline of "one")

("five" "six" seven" are not downlines of "one" cz they are not the downline of downline of "one" i means they have joined under "two" who is not a downline of "one" thats why they are not in the tree)

```
                     one
                      |
    ----------------------------------------------------
    |                          |                       |
    two                       three                   four
     |                         |                       |
  ----------------------      ---------------------    ---------------------
  |      |             |      |       |           |    |        |          |
 five   six        seven      eight   nine      ten    eleven   twelve   thirteen
```

so if my table has two columns as "user_id"  (primary key)
and "referal id"  as (which pints  to the id under which this new user id is created)

then what will be the  select query to find all the downlines of "one"

i will be really greatfull to get the answer.

Comment: which sql server? : your keywords:  connect by , recursive queries

Comment: plz give a descriptive answer sir

Comment: If you are lucky, this will only cost you $100 at rent-a-coder.com, elance.com or guru.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if oracle you can use connect by clause :
for turkish :   [oracle connect by](http://www.tufyta.com/oracle-connect-by-soyagaci-sorgulama)
for english : [oracle connect by](http://psoug.org/reference/connectby.html)

```
SELECT tckimlik,adi, SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(adi, '->') AS konum
FROM ailem
CONNECT BY PRIOR tckimlik=baba_tc
START WITH baba_tc IS NULL
```

Result :

[image]

```
SELECT  LPAD('-',LEVEL,'-')|| adi sahis,tckimlik,baba_tc,LEVEL
FROM  ailem
START WITH baba_tc IS NULL
CONNECT BY PRIOR tckimlik=baba_tc
```

Result :

[image]

hierarchical data in mysql : 
http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Comment: please give me the sample select query sir i am not understanding your answer

Comment: can someone convert it in english for me please

Comment: i think examples are enought,  english link added.

Comment: is the same code compatible with mysql or ms sql server? i am creating the application in mysql so i need mysql code

Comment: please indicate your development environment or server software in your question!

hierarchical data in mysql : 
http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/hierarchical-data.h

Comment: though i am not satisfied with the given solution as i am coding in mysql not in oracle so the connect_by is not working here.finally i have created my own login using the the code behing file the using c# programming i came to a solution of the above problem .i think it is not possible to get such a complex result in a single sql statement so i used c# programming.well thanks for ur help mentors